# How to get bokeh or macro on E-M10 Mark II with 14-42mm Black EZ Lens?

Tags: aperture, macro, olympus, bokeh, kit-lens

I got E-M10 Mark II with 14-42mm Black EZ Lens f3.5-5.6 EZ.

Is it possible to create nice bokeh and macro pics with this set up?

I tried shooting many pics (well mainly on auto), but I never got bokeh. Unfortunately, it never got to focus properly on close-up objects. Not even proper macro. It just refuses to focus on close up objects. I get so much better results with my old iPhone 6.

I am very disappointed that I spent $600 on this, and I still use my iPhone.

Is it just wrong set up, or I need to do some "magic trick" to get bokeh and macro out of this camera and kit lens?

If it is possible to do, how do I do it?

Comment: @PhilipKendall how is that? i dont even understand the question... and i am asking specifically about my kit..

Comment: @osullic Yeah, I understand that. :(